# What can I use to integrate Push-to-Talk functionality in the chat module of my application

Tags: asterisk

Which tools/servers etc would be needed? Is there any articles or something that I could read along and follow to help me create the functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that your chat application is a web app. You could integrate it with asterisk through a library suporting sip (e.g. sip.js) working on top of WebRTC. In WebRTC, the sources and sinks of media streams come or go to audio (or video) tags that have attributes as muted (see [HTML Audio/Video DOM muted Property](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_muted.asp)) than can be managed by the app to simulate PTT. The PTT can be implemented with a button in the app, with a keystroke or even with an USB HID device depending on how much do you enjoy struggling with external access to browsers (I certainly do).

There are alternatives involving some kind of third party control (AMI, for example), that would take advantage that ConfBridge can be controlled to mute participants on the fly. It all depends on the specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do real push-to-talk using asterisk/sip.

Just becuase sip connect sequence take 0.5-1second usually.

Best option is use your own custom app which will maintain sip session(send sip ping every few sec) upto X(for example 1minute) second after last message, not send rtp if user not pressed key(but you still need send keapalive rtp to maintain NAT).